# gdb do not show the right source code by the instruction -l

Tags: c++, gdb

I have met a freaky problem during my internship. My work is to code with VTK in C++ and I worked on OSX 10.8.3.

---

When I want to debug my program, I ran the gdb and use instruction "file" to load my program, then I used "list" to show the source code to make a breakpoint by line number. Here goes the problem: this freaky gdb showed the source code of a VTK header file which I even hadn't included in my source code!

---

My program's name is read
I have tried to use `gdb read` then `break read:15` to set a breakpoint but the gdb displayed "`no source file named read`" that is ridiculous!
I have noticed that gdb works well in my ubuntu 12.04 and when I use `file read` in linux's gdb, it just displayed

```
Reading symbols from /Users/apple/Dev/VTKRead/bin/bin/read...done.
```

but in my OSX 10.8.3's freaky gdb it displayed

```
Reading symbols for shared libraries ......... done
Reading symbols from /Users/apple/Dev/VTKRead/bin/bin/read...done.
```

I think that is the reason and I tried to change compiler to solve problem by install gcc4.8 in macport but cmake seems only accept the apple's gcc.

Answer (score 1):

> but the gdb displayed "no source file named read" that is ridiculous!

That is *not* rigiculous at all: you very likely *don't* have a source file called `read`. What you do have is probably called `read.cc`, or `read.cpp`, so try `break read.cc:15`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have tried your method and that do not work. My source file name is read6.cpp and I tired use "break read6.cpp:15" osx's gdb showed also "no source file named read6.cpp" The key problem is that this creepy gdb can not load the source code. I doubt that the gdb on osx can not read the apple's gcc's output file.

Answer (score 0):

That is my mistake: I didn't set the build tag to "debug" in ccmake, so the compiler didn't write the information into the file.